# How to Validate Post Meta type/extension (Video File Image File etc)

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I am trying to learn meta's in Wordpress by taking an example of the already existing meta →

```
function cpmb_display_meta_box( $post ) {

// Define the nonce for security purposes
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'cpmb-nonce-field' );

// Start the HTML string so that all other strings can be concatenated
$html = '';

// If the current post has an invalid file type associated with it,
// then display an error message.
if ( 'invalid-file-type' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mp3', true ) ) {

    $html .= '<div id="invalid-file-type" class="error">';
        $html .= '<p>You are trying to upload a file other than an MP3.</p>';
    $html .= '</div>';

}

// Display the 'Title of MP3' label and its text input element
$html .= '<label id="mp3-title" for="mp3-title">';
    $html .= 'Title Of MP3';
$html .= '</label>';
$html .= '<input type="text" id="mp3-title" name="mp3-title" value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mp3-title', true ) . '" placeholder="Your Song By Elton John" />';

// Display the 'MP3 File' label and its file input element
$html .= '<label id="mp3-file" for="mp3-file">';
    $html .= 'MP3 File';
$html .= '</label>';
$html .= '<input type="file" id="mp3-file" name="mp3-file" value="" />';

    echo $html;

}
```

The above function is the function to render the markup in the backend?

My question is related to this line →

```
if ( 'invalid-file-type' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mp3', true ) ) {
```

It looks like to be validating whether the file is mp3 or not?

**The Main Question →** what if we want to validate whether this is  Video file? Video files can be of multiple types and can come from many sources such Vimeo, Youtube, facebook etc.

Additionally,

I request the reader of this post to guide me to some specific meta where oembed has been used successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post's metadata can not and should not be used for validation. They can be easily manipulated. Post metadata simply stores *"editable"* strings or arrays, nothing more than that.

The code you have copied is trying to fetch a metadata and check if its value is `mp3`. You can change a value of `exe` to `mp3`, and it will assume that the file is mp3. So, security issue here.

To validate a file truly, you have to pass the files path or URL to a real validator.

For example, WordPress offers this function to validate an image:

```
file_is_valid_image( $path );
```

Which returns true is the file in the pass is a real image. There are function to retrieve the file's *real* extension (since it can easily be manipulated, change .exe to .jpg), which you can find them by a simple search.

Comment: sir, do you think that this is the function that checks all file types extension? → https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype

Comment: Yes you've found it! That's one of them. This function reads the file name, not its content. There was also another function that would really validate the file based on its real content, like `wp_check_realmime()`. I lose my 3G connection once in a while, so I can't search now. But I can do it after I get back in a few hours if you want.

Answer (score 1):

> The above function is the function to render the markup in the backend?

Correct.

> It looks like to be validating whether the file is mp3 or not?

No. It's just checking if the value of the meta has been set to literally the text 'invalid-file-type'. Whatever you got this from would be doing the validation in the save action, and if the filetype is invalid it sets the value of the meta to `'invalid-file-type'`.

Comment: ButI think that this is testing → `if ( 'invalid-file-type' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mp3', true ) ) {`
 whether the extension is `.mp3` or not.

Comment: No, it's not. That's what I'm telling you. It's checking if the `mp3` field is set to `invalid-file-type`. See the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) for `get_post_meta()`. The `mp3` is referring to the meta key.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation of meta box where the Video URL is embedded? Any example or Video Tutorial?